# MySQL Update with multiple Columns and databases

Tags: mysql

I have this script below which should update the `subscriber_id` in `subscriber_users` with the `id` from `subscriber` where the `email` from `subscriber` is in the oldDB.table as `emailSubscriber`

```
UPDATE subscription_users AS u
JOIN subscriber AS s
ON u.subscriber_id = s.id
set u.subscriber_id = s.id
where s.email IN (SELECT `emailSubscriber` FROM oldDB.table);
```

This code runs without any error, but the `id` in `subscriber` will never be set. So i'm guessing that the subselect won't work.

By the point this Querys runs `u.subscriber_id` is `null` and this Query won't select any entries nor update any. But i can gurantee that there are matching entries and the update should work.

What am i doing wrong?

**Trying to clearify things.**

I have three tables:

`subscriber` with the field `id` and `email`

`subscriber_users` with the field `subscriber_id`.

`subscriber_users` stands in a OneToMany relationship to `subscriber`.

Then there is an the `table` in another **database** with the field `emailSubscriber`.

I need a way to add the `id` from `subscriber` to the `subscriber_id` from `subscribers_users` when `subscriber.email` is in the `emailSubscriber` field from `oldDatabase.table`.

I think that the join is missleading and can't work because `subscriber_users.subscriber_id` is `null`, so of course there's no value to join. That's an error in my thought process.

This is the structure for subscriber

[image: subscriber structure]

This is the structure for subscription_users

[image: subcription_users structure]

The relation is the following:

```
1 subscriber - X subscription_users
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. are you trying to do a self join with the table `subscription_users`?

Comment: It was a typo in the join in the Question, i'm sorry that this was missleading

Comment: Yes, you got it correct. That's the problem cause your `u.subscriber_id is null` and so the join will never work but there can be a alternative. Post the table structure for `subscriber` and `subscriber_users`

Comment: done, edited in into the Question.

Answer (score 0):

You join by already equal values, but also want reset; For simple example

```
UPDATE `table` SET `value` = 5 WHERE `value` = 5;
```

Comment: `u.subscriber_id` is by the point i'm running this Query and no Entrys will be selected what so ever, i'll try to make it more clear